# Flash check when an external mp3 is completely loaded

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I´m loading some MP3 from an external URL.
I need to wait to completely load the mp3 and then start to play it.
Do you know how can I check when mp3 loads completely?

This is my code:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("url.com/file.mp3"));  
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
channel = s.play();
```

Best, Flavio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listener for the complete event of the sound object before calling play.  Also, since `Sound.play()` returns a SoundChannel object you don't need to instantiate one, just define a variable to hold it's reference outside the scope of the complete handler.

```
var channel:SoundChannel;
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("url.com/file.mp3")); 
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSoundLoaded);

function onSoundLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    s.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSoundLoaded);
    channel = s.play();
}
```